# Python Dictionary convert to HTML in flask

Tags: python, html, dictionary, flask

I have python dictionary that have a list of dictionaries inside. I am trying to convert this to an HTML table that I can give to Flask render_template

My dictionary format is:

```
{'sentiment_analysis_result': [{'article_title': u'These Digital Locks Help Keep Tabs on Tenants', 'score': u'0.139613', 'type': u'positive'}, {'article_title': u'You Can Get a $50 Phone From Amazon, If You Don\u2019t Mind the Ads', 'score': u'0.239663', 'type': u'positive'}]}
```

I want the key to be title and values to be values. Any help would be much apprecited!

After trying @EliasMP 's answer the format of the table is:

[image]

Comment: Just pass the dictionary from controller to template and loop it twice. First one for recover each element of dictionary (key and value respectly), and the second one for recovering each element of each list (value recovered before), paint them using html (table tag, div formatted as a table would be the proper way, table´s tag are being obsolete).

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the dictionary from controller to template and loop it twice. First one for recovering each element of dictionary (key and value respectly), and the second one for recovering each element of each list (value recovered before), paint them using html (table tag, div formatted as a table would be the proper way, table´s tag are being obsolete)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>name_of_list</th>
        <th>values</th>
    </tr>

    {% for key, values in your_dictionary.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>
        <table>
           <tr>
             <th>article_title</th>
             <th>score</th>
             <th>type</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           {% for articles in values %}
               <td>{{article.article_title}}</td>
               <td>{{article.score}}</td>
               <td>{{article.type}}</td>
           {% endfor %}
           </tr>
        </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does name_of_list and values represent here?

Comment: Wellcome @Pythoner1234 I was supossing you want to paint it, as a table with two column, first one the name´s list, and second one each value of the list. So first column contains the name´s list (first value of dictionary - key) and the second one will be another table with its values (loop over value´s dictionary, means the list).

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the code and got the following error for some reason
   {% for key, values in my_dictionary.items %}
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: Sorry @Pythoner1234. Edited. Guessing is missing items()

Comment: I just edited the question to include an image of the table. For some reason table seems disoriented. Please look at my main post @EliasMP

Comment: Ups @Pythoner1234. Just trying, not tested, but after recover the list, each element will be a dictionary, so you have to loop it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121791/discussion-between-eliasmp-and-pythoner1234).

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but gets the job done if you want to just pass the table already rendered as html as a variable to the view. A better way would be to pass just the data then have the template use template logic to loop over and output variables in the places you want.

```
data = {'sentiment_analysis_result': [{'article_title': u'These Digital Locks Help Keep Tabs on Tenants', 'score': u'0.139613', 'type': u'positive'}, {'article_title': u'You Can Get a $50 Phone From Amazon, If You Don\u2019t Mind the Ads', 'score': u'0.239663', 'type': u'positive'}]}

table_string = '<table>'
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    table_string += '<thead>'
    table_string += '<th>' + key + '</th>'
    table_string += '</thead>'
    table_string += '<tbody>'
    for i, d in enumerate(value):
        if i == 0:
            table_string += '<tr>'
            for k in d.iterkeys():
                table_string += '<td>' + k + '</td>'
            table_string += '</tr>'
        table_string += '<tr>'
        for v in d.itervalues():
            table_string += '<td>' + v + '</td>'
        table_string += '</tr>'
    table_string += '</tbody>'
table_string += '</table>'

print(table_string)
```